# Simplifying Codes on one line in Jquery

Tags: jquery, optimization

I have this lines of codes. Could this be possible to simplify this in a single line?

Like this:

> toggleWithVisibility (bridge, $('#bridge'); road, $('#road'); rail, ('#rail'); ... );

```
    function toggleWithVisibility(source, target) {
        source.on('change:visible', function(){
            if (source.getVisible() == true) {
                target.show();                        
            } else {
                target.hide();
            }
        });
    }

    toggleWithVisibility(bridge, $('#bridge'));
    toggleWithVisibility(road, $('#road'));
    toggleWithVisibility(rail, $('#rail'));
    toggleWithVisibility(contour, $('#contour'));
    toggleWithVisibility(waterL, $('#rivers'));
    toggleWithVisibility(dividerP, $('#divider'));
    toggleWithVisibility(building, $('#building'));
    toggleWithVisibility(vegePoly, $('#vegetation'));
    toggleWithVisibility(waterP, $('#waterbodies'));
    toggleWithVisibility(slope50, $('#slope'));
    toggleWithVisibility(dem50, $('#dem'));
```

Comment: Let us show your Javascript code or post as jsfiddle.

Comment: Wait a sec, I'll edit my question! ... and It's done!

Comment: may be you could pass an array like `[{source: source1, target: target1}, {source: source2, target: target2]` and iterate over the array in the function.

Comment: I'm assuming these are some type of `<input>` elements. This can be improved by using proper selectors. If you can update the post to include a more complete example, can show you.

Answer (score 1):

Just put all your **key** and **id** into a **array** and call function in the loop as below

```
 $(function(){
var ar = [
{key:'key1',id:'id1'},
{key:'key2',id:'id2'},
{key:'key3',id:'id3'},
{key:'key4',id:'id4'},
];
$.each( ar, function( key, value ) {
  test(value.key,$('#'+value.id));
});
});
function test(key,ele){
console.log(key);
console.log(ele);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in an array and use `.forEach` to loop over it.

```
[
    [bridge, $("#bridge")],
    [road, $('#road')],
    [rail, $('#rail')],
    ...
].forEach(el => toggleWithVisibility.apply(null, el)));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be made into a single line. You can pass all the data to the function via an Object. The function can then apply the binding of each object.

I have to assume that `bridge` is a variable or element that is assigned someplace else. For example, if it `<input type="checkbox" id="bridge-check" />`, the you can use something like:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").filter(":visible").on("change", function(e) {
  var source = $(this);
  var target = $("#" + source.data("target"));
  if (source.getVisible()) {
    target.show();
  } else {
    target.hide();
  }
});
```

Now this does require a small change, adding a `data` attribute. So you'd want something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="bridge-chkbx" data-target="bridge" /><label for "bridge-chkbx">Use Bridge</label>
```

Hope that helps.